# Parse error when run illuminate/database/capsule with bootEloquent() in PHP

Tags: php, eloquent, composer-php, slim

I'm trying to make a mysql connection within a php environment using Slim and the package `illuminate/database`. Following the documentation I have created a new $capsule instance, I have passed the array with connection data through the `addConnection` method and then I have run `bootEloquent()` method:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;


$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
  'driver' => $app->config->get('db.driver'),
  'host' => $app->config->get('db.host'),
  'database' => $app->config->get('db.database'),
  'username' => $app->config->get('db.username'),
  'password' => $app->config->get('db.password'),
  'charset' => $app->config->get('db.charset'),
  'collation' => $app->config->get('db.collation'),
  'prefix' => $app->config->get('db.prefix')
]);

#here the output seems correct...
#var_dump($capsule);

$capsule->bootEloquent();


 ?>
```

Unfortunately when I run bootEloquent() it goes through an error:

> Parse error: parse error in
>   /Sites/auth/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 597

The problem seems related to the **Eloquent Model**.
I have already tried to update the composer.json file with different versions. I have also installed again each package, but the parse error still remains.

Currently the project is running on: **PHP Version 5.6.30.**

#### My current composer json file with all dependencies

```
{
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Business\\": "app/Business"
      }
    },
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "0.8.*",
        "illuminate/database": "~5.0",
        "alexgarrett/violin": "2.*",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1"
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why I'm getting this strange bad situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the line giving you the error, your current `composer.json` and the PHP version running that code?

Comment: @NicoHaase sure. Current version of PHP: **PHP Version 5.6.30**. For the composer I'll update the question in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `composer.lock` to see which version of `illuminate/database` got installed. The later ones are not compatible with PHP 5.6.30, but require PHP 7. You could try to enforce that version constraint through `"illuminate/database": "~5.4.0"`

Comment: You saved me! With this version the parse error has finally disappeared. 
If I had not solved the problem with dependencies versioning changes, how should I have done? Maybe upgrade the PHP version to 7.1?

Comment: Yes, that might be one solution. Keep in mind that this can cause new problems, as there are some minor breaking changes. But for the long-term view, you should consider it as PHP 7 is much faster and the security support for 5.6 will end in some months