# I have a parse error using eloquent with slim3

Tags: php

I'm following the codecourse video series Authentication with Slim 3, which is about 3 years old. 
I've hit a snag when it comes to using eloquent to access a mysql database.
(the relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70IkLMkPyPs )

the code wasn't quite the same as that currently recommended on the instructions on illuminate/database's docs, so I've modified the code slightly to follow that standard, but regardless of whether I follow Alex's code oon the vid or the following, a parse error results.

```
$app = new \Slim\App([
  'settings' => [
    'displayErrorDetails' => true,

    'db' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'database' => 'opium3',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    ]

  ],

]);


$container = $app->getContainer();

/*set up eloquent to use outside laravel*/
use \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Running the app produced this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/public/opium3/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php on line 65

I'm running this locally on a scotchbox vagrant set up, if that's relevant.
There's a similar question at
[Parse error when run illuminate/database/capsule with bootEloquent() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204674/parse-error-when-run-illuminate-database-capsule-with-booteloquent-in-php)

but this answer doesn't resolve my issue, since the server is running php7.
I have also tried installing packages recommended by illuminate/database, installing php-mbstring, and editing the php.ini file, on the server, but the error persists.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I see the question has been downvoted. Any tips as to how it could be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using at least PHP 7.1.

`/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php` is using a short hand version of the `list()`-construct which wasn't available until PHP 7.1.

The "old" way is to:

```
list($var1, $var2) = someFunction();
```

while you, since PHP 7.1, can also do:

```
[$var1, $var2] = someFunction();
```

The row the error is thrown in is this:

```
[$database, $type] = $this->parseConnectionName($name);
```

**Note:**

If you can't upgrade your PHP version from 7.0 to 7.1.3+, you need to use an older version of the `Illuminate/Database`-package. Use version 5.5 for PHP 7.0 and then 5.6+ on PHP 7.1.3+